# CakePHP find list with group name same as data name

Tags: list, cakephp, select, cakephp-2.0

I have to show a select box with the different movie genres grouped by general genres.
To do so, I'm using the CakePHP default method `find('list',...)`.

My database table for movie genres is done like so:

```
|_id_|_name_________|_general_genre_|
|  1 | Action       | Action        |
|  2 | Martial arts | Action        |
| .. | ............ | ............. |
```

The problem is that if the group has the same name as the data (e.g.: "Action") the data is not shown in benefit of the group name.

So my select box looks like:

```
Select a genre
  - Action
    - Martial arts
    - ...
```

And what I would like is:

```
Select a genre
  - Action
    - Action
    - Martial arts
    - ...
```

Of course, the reason is, it's not possible to select a group item.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, after some more research I finaly get the answer.
This is an attribute to add to the `Html->input()` method. This attribute is `showParents`.
So, if you want to make a select box with groups and have, inside this group, items with the same name that this group, you have to do something like this:

- Select the list with the groups:

  ```
  $options = $this->TableName->find('list', array(
     'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'group_name')
  ));
  ```
- Show the select input:

  ```
  $this->Html->input('InputId', array(
     'type' => 'select',
     'options' => $options,
     'showParents' => true
  ));
  ```

Hope this can help ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior. Use the `showParents` option when generating the form element. The   [API](http://api.cakephp.org/class/form-helper#method-FormHelperselect) even has an eg. for this case which you failed to check :)

Comment: Yes, I already realized my mistake and answered my question. In fact I read the CookBook and didn't thought about the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default fields that a `find('list')` returns (which are the primary key and the displayField) by your own fields, by setting the `$options['fields']` option. These can be more than two fields if you need to. This should come close to what you need:

```
$this->Genre->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('id', 'name', 'general_genre')
));
```

This will return an array like:

```
'Action' => 
    1 => 'Action'
    2 => 'Martial arts'
```

You should be able to use that in a dropdown.

Comment: In fact this is what a do but if the group has the same name as the list item (e.g.: "Action") the item is not displayed. So it return something like: `'Action' => 2 => 'Martial arts'`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm saying a stupidity. The find method is doing the job right. What's wrong is the `Html->input()` method. This is at this moment that the elemnt "Action" is removed...